# Meteor stop working after upgrading

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to correctly upgrade meteor on Windows XP platform? After that, nonthing happen when i run "meteor" to start my app (no messages on console)

Thanks

Andrea

Comment: I upgrade to 0.5.4, but honestly i don't remember the previous version. IMHO i think that it was just 0.5.4, so i don't understand why ask me to upgrade.

Comment: It sounds like fibers: https://github.com/TomWij/meteor/issues/52. You'll have to wait for the next windows meteor release

Comment: or roll back of course

Answer (score 0):

I believe the latest releases of Meteor for Windows will have fixed this issue.
Please could you try version 0.6.3.1 or above.